# Crypto-Currency price API with price listed in USD?

Tags: ios, api, web-apis, bitcoin, currency-converter

I am working on an app that will display the current price of crypto-currencies in a similar fashion to the stock app in iOS 8. The app is written in Swift. I am looking for an API that will allow me to get the price of the many crypto currencies (not just bitcoin) in USD.

This API must either be web-based, or have a library provided in either Objective-C or Swift. It must be free. It must not force me to login or make an account to use it.

So far, all the API's which support multiple currencies I have found list the prices in terms of Bitcoin instead. I am aware that I can convert the Bitcoin price presented to its USD equivalent, however this would require bringing in a second API, and considering the fluctuation in price of Bitcoin, and the extra API calls that would have to occur, this to me is a non-option.

Is there an API out there that supports my needs?

Answer (score 0):

The Shapeshift API is your friend: https://shapeshift.io